# Unity MVC using SOA and gereric Repository and UnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I am trying to put together a project that is based on SOA and uses Gereric Repository and UnitOfWork along with Unity.

My problem is that when the controllers try to initialize I get the following error:

**The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.**

I have the following Unity Configuration:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{ 

    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();    

        container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, MyDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IRepositoryProvider, RepositoryProvider>(
                    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
                    new InjectionConstructor(new object[] { new RepositoryFactories() })
                    )
                 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<ApplicationSetting>, Repository<ApplicationSetting>>()
                 .RegisterType<IApplicationSettingService, ApplicationSettingService>();

        container.RegisterType<IRepositoryProvider, RepositoryProvider>(new InjectionConstructor(container));


    }
}
```

The following Activator

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;
using XNETProductQuote.Web; 

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]


namespace XNETProductQuote.Web  
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My controller that I am trying to load is the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using XNETProductQuote.Entities ;
using XNETProductQuote.Entities.Models;
using XNETProductQuote.Service;

namespace XNETProductQuote.Controllers
{
    public class ApplicationSettingController : Controller
    {

        private IApplicationSettingService service;

    public ApplicationSettingController(IApplicationSettingService svr)         
    { 
        service = svr;
    }

    //
    // GET: /ApplicationSetting/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var applicationSettings = service.GetAll();
        return View(applicationSettings); 
    }



}
```

As far as I can see the Unityconfig Registers the IApplicationSettingService type that should be used to initialise the controller.

am I missing something else?

UPDATE:

The error I get is

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.]
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext context) +299
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +131
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey) +162
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +245
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +167
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +222
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +167
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +232
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +167
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +222
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +167
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +224
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +384

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "XNETProductQuote.Controllers.ApplicationSettingController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving XNETProductQuote.Controllers.ApplicationSettingController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "svr" of constructor XNETProductQuote.Controllers.ApplicationSettingController(XNETProductQuote.Service.IApplicationSettingService svr)
    Resolving XNETProductQuote.Service.ApplicationSettingService,(none) (mapped from XNETProductQuote.Service.IApplicationSettingService, (none))
    Resolving parameter "repository" of constructor XNETProductQuote.Service.ApplicationSettingService(Repository.Pattern.Repositories.IRepositoryAsync`1[[XNETProductQuote.Entities.Models.ApplicationSetting, XNETProductQuote.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] repository)
      Resolving Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Repository`1[XNETProductQuote.Entities.Models.ApplicationSetting],(none) (mapped from Repository.Pattern.Repositories.IRepositoryAsync`1[XNETProductQuote.Entities.Models.ApplicationSetting], (none))
      Resolving parameter "context" of constructor Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Repository`1[[XNETProductQuote.Entities.Models.ApplicationSetting, XNETProductQuote.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync context, Repository.Pattern.UnitOfWork.IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork)
        Resolving XNETProductQuote.Entities.MyDbContext,(none) (mapped from Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync, (none))
        Resolving parameter "connectionString" of constructor XNETProductQuote.Entities.MyDbContext(System.String connectionString)
          Resolving System.String,(none)
]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +447
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +50
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +48
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides) +61
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +142
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +87

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XNETProductQuote.Controllers.ApplicationSettingController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +438
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +226
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +326
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

My Repository class is as follow

```
    public static class ApplicationSettingRepository
{
    public static ApplicationSetting GetByID(this IRepository<ApplicationSetting> repository, int applicationSettingId)
    {
        return repository.Find(applicationSettingId);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApplicationSetting> GetAll(this IRepository<ApplicationSetting> repository)
    {
        return repository.Queryable().AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Controller injects the `IApplicationSettingService` dependency. Does IApplicationSettingsService inject a dependency? Does its dependency inject a dependency... Somewhere in the chain you are missing a registration. You'll need to post more details about the source of the error.

Comment: I have added more details above. I think is because of the repository implementation but not sure.

Comment: Jasen. ApplicationSettingService has a constructor that takes as an argument IRepositoryAsync<ApplicationSetting>. I have also included this in the registering types. See .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<ApplicationSetting>, Repository<ApplicationSetting>>()

Comment: It looks like your `MyDbContext` requires a connection string argument but you do not specify this in your registration.